# Symfony - translations stop working after rendering controler in another's view

Tags: symfony

I'm building a webiste, where there will be lots of "widgets" displayed on the front page. One of them is the calendar. 
I wanted to make a new controller for each this "widget", and then render them all (like the example below), in the Homepage view. 
Hovewer - the translations stop working after that. If I visit `mywebpage/calendar`, they work, but not when I got to `mywebpage/home`.

This is the code I currently have for my Homepage view.

```
{% block Calendar %}
    {{ render(controller('MyWebsite:Calendar:index')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Am I approaching this correctly or not? And why do the translations stop working?
Also - I hope you will understand what the issue is :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that doesn't work, do you have anything else in your app interfering with the `Request` object?

Maybe passing the locale from the request as an argument to the controller may work (although a bit of a hack)?

```
{% block Calendar %}
    {{ render(controller('MyWebsite:Calendar:index', { _locale: app.request.locale })) }}
{% endblock %}
```